# clean letters and characters in files leaving only numbers using bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sh

I am reading files and  i am doing something like:

```
  cat file  | sed s/\ //g |awk '$0 !~ /[^0-9]/'
```

With this line I want to clean anything different to numbers.

But i have a problem, when the file is not sorted the command works fine, but with a sorted file the command not works, the output is empty.

Who can help me?

with grep -o '[0-9]+' not works because:

I have a file like:

```
311435ll3e
kk13322;.

erre433
```

The output is:

```
311435
3
13322
433
```

And the 3 is in the second line, the output that i need is:

```
3114353
13322
433
```

Comment: we'll need to see a sample from `file`, and please clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.  I don't understand what you mean by _clean anything different to numbers_

Comment: Can we assume that the input is a line-oriented file, each line having either a token consisting only of digits or a token that may have digits but also has non-digits?  Do you want only the lines that have digit-only tokens?

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, there is no reason to have both awk and sed appearing in the same pipe, due to a large overlap of capability, and frequently the same is true of awk/grep/sed combinations.

If you just want to suppress the non-digit characters within lines of characters, use (eg) `sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' file`, or if you want to do it in place with no backup, `sed -i -e 's/[^0-9]//g' file`, or  in place with backup to a .bak file, `sed -ibak -e 's/[^0-9]//g' file`.

To suppress blank lines, you can append `|egrep -v '^$'` after the sed, but it's more efficient to just use sed's `d` command to delete the pattern space and start next cycle if the pattern space is empty.  For example,
`sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g; /^$/d' file`
does a `d` if the line is empty after substitution.

The form suggested in 1_CR's comment,
`sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' -e '/./!d'`
is an alternative.  That form tests if the line has at least one character in it, and if so does *not* do a `d`.

If you want to suppress everything in the file that's not digits, use  `tr -cd 0-9 < file`.  This suppresses line feeds also.

Note, the form `tr -cd [0-9] < file` or `tr -cd '[0-9]' < file` is not correct; it will fail to suppress `]` and `[` characters because `tr` will regard them as part of SET1.

Comment: The problem with `sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'` file is that the empty lines appear in the output, and i need remove the empty lines too, like the example that i have

Comment: Then add a `|egrep -v '^$'` after the sed.  Note, you could use sed directives to detect and not print blank lines but I don't remember the directives without looking them up.

Comment: I add the `grep -v '^$'` and it works fine, thanks =')

Comment: No need for grep or egrep to suppress empty lines, just extend sed like so `sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' -e '/./!d'`

Comment: @1_CR, I was about to edit and add the form `/^$/d` when I saw your comment